# Adding Noise for tests

Tags: noise

I have written a few clustering algorithms to understand them. They run perfectly fine. But I would like to know how well they work when noise is added. I'm not really sure how to add noise to my data.

Is it enough to take a small perturbation in each item such as

> Original: 1, 2.34, 3.2346, 4.234, 5.235, 6.245, 7.45
>             2, 3.54, 4.2646, 2.24, 4.25, 6.25, 4.5 ....

The new would find the variance of each column and then add that to each element of the column.

Or do I add a new item set which would be away from each cluster? If so how would I do that?

Comment: hi, what about [gaussian noise](http://www.dspguru.com/dsp/howtos/how-to-generate-white-gaussian-noise)?

Comment: I think that's a good idea. But how should I add the Gaussian noise?

Comment: what programming language do you use?

Comment: I can add Gaussian noise in Matlab really fast. So I think I will use that.

Comment: matlab is great! Check out [`imnoise`](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/toolbox/images/ref/imnoise.html)

Comment: That is for images. How would I do it for an m x n matrix?

Comment: Is this The right way to do it?
Matrix = Matrix + randn(m,n) ?

Comment: `noisy = original + randn(size(original));` randn generates gaussian noise with zero mean and unit variance

Comment: Thank you for that calcification!